# EF. Required validation error for string fields raise without [Required] attribute

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, validation, mvvm

**Problem:**

When adding new item into EntityCollectionView raised the required validation for string fields, but for my purpose we should show it after validation on server side.


**Actual behavior:**

Here is code from metadata file:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(SomeEntityMetadata))]
public partial class SomeEntity
{
    [EntityName]
    internal sealed class SomeEntityMetadata
    {
        private SomeEntityMetadata()
        {
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }

        [EntityName(Name = "Name", OrderIndex = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [EntityName(Name = "Data Type", OrderIndex = 1)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And a collection of this items binded to `DataGrid` in xaml:

```
<navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True"
                                   CanUserSort="True"
                                   Header="Name"
                                   SortMemberPath="Name">
    <navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="Auto"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserFilter="True"
                                         CanUserSort="True"
                                         Header="Type"
                                         SortMemberPath="Type">
    <navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Type}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypes, Source={StaticResource entityViewModel}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</navigation:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As you see there  is no `[Required]` attributes for fields, but when inserting new item with `Name` and `Type` fields set to `String.Empty` the errors *"Name field is required"* and  *"Type field is required"* appears.

**Needed behavior:**
Skip required validation and throw `ValidationException` from server when `Name` or `Type` fields are empty.

NOTE: Silverlight, EF, WCF RIA, MVVM.

Comment: If you want to throw validation exception itself then why you want to do it from server anyway, in order to save round trip from server, it was made easier by wcf Ria services.

Comment: @AkashKava, you're right, but I need do some complicated checking within context.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For this you can set

```
 [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)]
```

On properties you want to pass through.